# ActiveJob Fails with 'Uninitialized Constant GuestsCleanupJob' Error After OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, actioncable, rails-activejob

I'm currently using ActionCable to broadcast a JWT token once a user has been authenticated. I've scheduled the broadcast to occur 4 seconds after authentication because I'm redirecting the client to the login page first and then want to broadcast the JWT token.

Application job Class

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :mailers

  def perform(devise_mailer, method,user_id, *args)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    devise_maier.send(method,user,*args).deliver_now
  end

end
```

In my google_oauth2 action within the OmniauthCallbacksController, I have the following code:

```
  def google_oauth2
  # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: 'Google'        
    sign_in @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
    token = Warden::JWTAuth::UserEncoder.new.call(@user, :user, nil)[0].to_s                          
    binding.pry
    GuestsCleanupJob.set(wait: 2.second).perform_now(token)
    redirect_to "http://127.0.0.1:3002/", allow_other_host: true  
  else
    session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra') # Removing extra as it can overflow some session stores
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
  end
```

end

I'm scheduling the broadcast by passing it to an ActiveJob queue that runs in Sidekiq. Here's the relevant code:

```
   class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(token)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "ChatChannel", {"type":"token","token":"Bearer #{token}"}       
  end
end
```

However, the ActiveJob fails with the following error logs:

```
2023-11-03T05:13:31.936Z pid=87046 tid=1fjq WARN: 
2023-11-03T05:13:52.419Z pid=87046 tid=1fl6 class=GuestsCleanupJob jid=5b449cba56dbda04714ea023 INFO: start
2023-11-03T05:13:52.471Z pid=87046 tid=1fl6 class=GuestsCleanupJob jid=5b449cba56dbda04714ea023 elapsed=0.053 INFO: fail
2023-11-03T05:13:52.471Z pid=87046 tid=1fl6 WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"retry":true,"queue":"default","class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"GuestsCleanupJob","args":[{"job_class":"GuestsCleanupJob","job_id":"f3e429cb-2ad3-4259-92e1-4816b8b674af","provider_job_id":null,"queue_name":"default","priority":null,"arguments":["eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJmYjA1NDQ0Zi03ZmQ0LTRhZTItYTMwOS0xOTMwZTc3ZWFjYWQiLCJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NwIjoidXNlciIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNjk4OTg4MzYxLCJleHAiOjE2OTg5OTAxNjF9.0yEhVrnFuYo8ZYE3G3cpbMe34dGJDU8jeTX3g8plqWU"],"executions":0,"exception_executions":{},"locale":"en","timezone":"UTC","enqueued_at":"2023-11-03T05:13:07Z"}],"jid":"5b449cba56dbda04714ea023","created_at":1698988387.1106932,"enqueued_at":1698988432.414398,"error_message":"uninitialized constant GuestsCleanupJob\n\n      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)\n            ^^^^^^^^^^","error_class":"NameError","failed_at":1698988389.918184,"retry_count":1,"retried_at":1698988411.9304},"_config":{"labels":"#<Set: {}>","require":".","environment":"development","concurrency":1,"timeout":25,"poll_interval_average":null,"average_scheduled_poll_interval":5,"on_complex_arguments":"raise","error_handlers":["#<Proc:0x000000010fe27560 /Users/moinahmed/moin_blog/backendapp/.bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:37 (lambda)>"],"death_handlers":[],"lifecycle_events":{"startup":[],"quiet":[],"shutdown":[],"heartbeat":[],"beat":["#<Proc:0x00000001105365b8 /Users/moinahmed/moin_blog/backendapp/.bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/metrics/tracking.rb:133>"]},"dead_max_jobs":10000,"dead_timeout_in_seconds":15552000,"reloader":"#<Sidekiq::Rails::Reloader @app=Backend::Application>","backtrace_cleaner":"#<Proc:0x00000001128ebe40 /Users/moinahmed/moin_blog/backendapp/.bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:59 (lambda)>","queues":["default","mailers"],"config_file":"./config/sidekiq.yml","tag":"backendapp","identity":"Moins-MacBook-Air.local:87046:f520db71521f"}}
2023-11-03T05:13:52.473Z pid=87046 tid=1fl6 WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant GuestsCleanupJob

      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
```

I'd appreciate any help or insights into why the ActiveJob is failing with the "uninitialized constant GuestsCleanupJob" error.

I tried add namespace around my ActiveJob class

```
    module Jobs
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(token)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "ChatChannel", {"type":"token","token":"Bearer #{token}"}       
  end
end
end
```

But the above changes throws same errors

NameError: uninitialized constant Jobs

FYI
**the application job that sends devise mailer works fine without any issue**

RUBY VERSION: 3.*.*
RAILS.   7

Comment: I see, the path for GuestsCleanupJob.rb is app/jobs/guests_cleanup_job.rb

Comment: After add ing the namespace around the class defineation, I get following error
------------------
```ruby
module Jobs
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
queue_as :default

ruby
Copy code
def perform(token)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "ChatChannel", {"type":"token","token":"Bearer #{token}"}
end
end
end
```
------------------
error
Zeitwerk::NameError: expected file /Users/moinahmed/backendapp/app/jobs/guests_cleanup_job.rb to define constant GuestsCleanupJob, but didn't

Comment: I tried to run 
***GuestsCleanupJob.set(wait: 2.second).perform_later('token')*** in console, again same error,
it return the following object tough
#<GuestsCleanupJob:0x00000001096296c0
 @arguments=["token"],
 @exception_executions={},
 @executions=0,
 @job_id="3fe2b92f-a269-4576-a90c-164b44d64af4",
 @priority=nil,
 @provider_job_id="287e7b2624a36065d86986df",
 @queue_name="default",
 @scheduled_at=1699045838.294488,
 @successfully_enqueued=true,
 @timezone="UTC">

Comment: Three things: 1) make sure there is no other class named GuestsCleanupJob. 2) try commenting out the perform method in the ApplicationJob class. 3) Does the call in the console work if you remove the .set() call?

Comment: The job works fine if use perform_now, without setting any delay, with perform_later, i am getting the error, so the issue is with perform later